# Foursquare API: get all check-ins at a place for a period of time

Tags: api, geolocation, foursquare

Is it possible to get a list of people checked-in (publicly) at some place at some time interval? I read about Venues endpoint, but I guess it doesn't provide such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get check-ins of others (not friend) to maintain privacy. Instead, You can get whether your friends have checked-in at a place in the past.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues

```
friendVisits: {
    count: 41
    summary: "You and 40 friends have been here"
    items: [
        {
            // info about your friends
```